# How do I define a method once and use it as a "building plan" for other methods?

Tags: java, methods, setter, getter, universal

I'm new to Java and have the following question:
Is there an easier way of making methods for each variable?

The meaning behind the question is:
Do I have to define a method that does the exact same thing as other methods except that they use different variable names and types?

I think the most common methods with the same problem are the get- and set-accessors:
They share the same structure, the only difference are the variable types and names.

In my following example, you need to know:

> 1. Variables varA-varD just represent the existance of multiple variables with various types and names.
> 2. The variable "inheritor" is special. I **do NOT** implement inheritance, but I **DO** have to verify that somewhere, maybe in the inheritor of the inheritor of the inheritor the same variable
>
>    - has a value ("!= null"; in case of Lists, HashMaps, Enumerations, etc.)
>        or
>    - has a value other than -2 (because 0 means nothing and -1 indicates "infinite" in my system, so I thought using -2 for indicating that the variable hasn't been set yet is a good idea; in case of Integers, Floats, Doubles, etc.).
> 3. I have verification methods...
>
>    - ...to check whether the variables have already been set (or not)
>        and for this reason the code is located
>    - ...outside of the setter because I have to check the variables even when they have not been set yet.

```
public class ExampleClass {

    private int varA;
    private String varB;
    private ExampleEnum varC;
    private List<OtherClass> varD;
    //there are more variables here...

    private ExampleClass inheritor; 

    public int getVarA() {
        return varA;
    }

    public void setVarA(int varA) {
        this.varA = varA;
    }

    public boolean validateVarA() {
        //-2 is "not set" for Integers
        if (varA == -2 && inheritor != null) { 
            return inheritor.getVarA() != -2;
        } else {
            return varA != -2;
        }
    }

    //Do I have to define three methods for each variable?
    //What if I had like 20 variables?!?
    //I would need 60 methods altough every third one
    //shares the same structure.

}
```

I needed some sort of "building plan" for a method:

```
public T getVar() {
    return var;
}

public void setVar(T var) {
    this.var = var;
}

public boolean verifyVar() {
    //How would I get the invalid value for each type?
    T invalidValue = ?;
    if (var == invalidValue && inheritor != null) { 
        return inheritor.getVar() != invalidValue;
    } else {
        return var != invalidValue;
    }
}
```

In the example above:

> - "Var" or "var" would be the variable name
>     and
> - "T" would be the type of var
> - I have no idea how I would get the invalid value...

Sorry in case I think too complicated and there is a simple answer to my question. Furthermore, I apologize for any grammar mistakes that may occur.

Comment: BTW - *"Define a method once and use it as a "building plan" for other methods?"*  Adding a '?' to the end of a statement, does *not* make it a question.. Whereas as *"**How to** define a method once and use it as a "building plan" for other methods?"* is.

Comment: It's almost like `verifyVar()` should take a parameter!

Comment: @AndrewThompson, "How to do something?" is not a question. It's not even a sentence. "How do I do something?" is a question.

Comment: While it is possible to create generic getters and setters, it will be very convoluted to use them. Since most IDEs auto-generate them it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @pamphlet  Oh, good point.  OTOH I'm prepared to consider it a question, and I think 98% of others would agree.  ;)

Comment: 1st conceptual thing: Why is some external entity responsible to verify variables? Objects should encapsulate and hide it as much as they can. 2nd conceptual thing: an Object should do [1 thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Why does it need so many fields?

Comment: This is a bad idea for a simple reason: it will literally obstruct you from ever adding functionality to a setter or a getter. You're assuming right now that your system will never need those arbitrary limits you've set and you're also assuming that the functionality for every setter & getter will be the same. Are you sure that this is behaviour you want?

Comment: @pamphlet  I could not resist filling out my thoughts on the matter on [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/141715/7423).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I don't like your thoughts, but am glad you shared them! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For generic getters and setters, there's always `Map<String, Object>`, but I'm pretty sure that's not what you want, so you should stick to the JavaBean conventions (as mentioned in the comments, any IDE would generate those for you and it makes total sense to have them according to OOP recommendations).

Any attempt to implement generic accessors would sooner or later become some `java.util.Map` with tones of reflection around it. If that's what you want, perhaps you should reconsider your model and switch your type-safe beans to some free-form types like map.

For validation, there's the `javax.validation` package (JSR-303).